# Estimating the correlation matrix of a jointly normal distribution when some variables are latent

Tags: maximum-likelihood, missing-data, expectation-maximization, polychoric

Suppose that $X_1,..,X_6$ are jointly normally distributed.

$f(\mathbf{x})= \frac{1}{\sqrt { (2\pi)^k|\boldsymbol \Sigma| } }  \exp\left(-{1 \over 2} (\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol\mu)^{\rm T} \boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1} ({\mathbf x}-\boldsymbol\mu)\right)$

Suppose we also know that $X_i \sim N(0,1) \forall i \in \{1,...,6\}$

We have data for $X_1, X_2, X_3$. However, we do not observe $X_4,..,X_6$ but only observe $X_4^*, X_5^*,X_6^*$.

Where

$X_k^* = j  \Longleftrightarrow \alpha_{k,j-1} < X_k \leq \alpha_{k,j}$ where $j = 0,...,m \quad \forall k \in \{4,5,6 \}$

$\alpha_{i,j}$ are all constants.

So we just observe ordered data for the last three variables, when the underlying variables is realized in a certain interval. I don't know what the intervals are but my objective is to estimate $\Sigma$ and I guess along the way $\alpha_{k,j}$.

There are routines that do this in SAS but I would like to implement this myself in Excel and Matlab.

My question is, is it meaningful to estimate all the correlations pairwise or should I do an MLE for the joint distribution including all 6 random variables and estimate everything together?

Can someone point me to some literature that details the implementation and perhaps suggest other ways of estimating $\Sigma$ ?

Comment: Do you have some reference to the methods SAS is using?

Comment: In SAS there seems to be an option that calculates the polychoric correlation matrix.  
proc freq;
           table x1 * x2 / plcorr converge=.001 maxiter=30;
           run;
I now know that these are called Polychoric and polyserial correlation matrices. I've found some papers on this but would still appreciate more references. Thanks

Comment: I don't use SAS but in STATA there is a command "polychoric X Y" that does the job.